# Speed Up python3 code, a codechef problem INSQ17R

Tags: python, algorithm, python-3.x, binary

I want Python code to sum up to nth integer and each integer multiplied by the number of '1' in its binary represented number. Here is my python code but it takes a long time for n >= 10**8 :

```
from functools import reduce
from operator import add
m = 10**9+7
for t in range(int(input())):
    n = int(input())
    w =reduce(add,tuple(i*bin(i).count('1') for i in range(1,n+1)))
print((w)%m)
```

Comment: Mention what does the question ask?

Comment: I hope this time I mentioned all the details.

Answer (score 0):

I have done in C++ You can check for your reference :

const long long mod = 1e9 + 7;

int main ()

{

int T;

cin >> T;

for (int t = 0; t < T; t++)

{

```
   int N, Nt;

   vector<int> Nb;

   long long mult = 1, sol = 0;

   cin >> N;

   N++;

   Nt = N;

   while (N > 0) {

       Nb.push_back(N % 2);

       N /= 2;

   }

   N = Nt;

   //reverse(Nb.begin(), Nb.end());

   vector<long long> g(Nb.size()), h(Nb.size()), cs(Nb.size());

   for (int i = 1; i < Nb.size(); i++) {

       g[i] = (g[i - 1] * 2 + mult) % mod;

       h[i] = (h[i - 1] * 2 + ((mult * (mult - 1)) / 2) + (g[i - 1] + mult) *
```

mult) % mod;

```
       mult = mult * 2;

   }

   mult = 1;

   for (int i = Nb.size() - 2; i >= 0; i--)


       cs[i] = cs[i + 1] + Nb[i + 1];

   for (int i = 0; i < Nb.size(); i++) {

       long long NN = N / (2 * mult);

       if (Nb[i]) {

           sol = (sol + 2 * NN * mult * (g[i] + cs[i] * mult) + h[i] + cs[i] *
```

((mult * (mult - 1)) / 2)) % mod;

```
       }

       mult = mult * 2;

   }

   cout << sol << endl;
```

}

return 0;

}
 `